# Are the notations $C[0,1]$ and $C([0,1])$ the same?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I've been looking at proofs for the maximal ideals of $C([0,1])$ and I'm finding the above notations used interchangeably.

I know that $C([0,1])$ denotes the ring of real continuous functions on the interval $[0,1]$, but does $C[0,1]$ also denote this same ring? And if so, why are there two similar notations for the same ring?

Comment: They are the same. It's the same reason why we write $f:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R^2$ mappings as $f(x,y)$ instead of the proper $f((x,y))$, it's easier to write and less cluttered.

Comment: it can. Also, I have seen these used for all complex-valued functions on the real interval. Always a good idea to check for each separate book or article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, they generally refer to the same thing. The main motivation is to avoid an unnecessarily-cluttered expression full of brackets and parentheses.